# Using Jquery validate plugin for negative value checking on change of the input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have multiple input boxes and I have to check whether the entered values are positive or negative using [jquery Validator plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate).

It is basically doing some calculation based on the value entered in the first input box.

The value entered must be positive, if not I should throw an error message saying the value must be positive or greater than zero.

Comment: post the some code you have, have tried or the one you have so far

Comment: Use the `min: 1` rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regex for validating numeric value. Code given below. The function will return true if input box contains numeric value (negative or positive)

```
function checkNumericValue(num)
{
var objRegExp  =  /(^-?\d\d*\.\d*$)|(^-?\d\d*$)|(^-?\.\d\d*$)/;
return objRegExp.test(num);
}
```

For checking -ve value, follow the link [How to check the value given is a positive or negative integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037669/how-to-check-the-value-given-is-a-positive-or-negative-integer)

Answer (score 13):

Use the `min` rule to specify that the minimum value is 1.

```
$("#formid").validate({
    rules: {
        fieldname: {
           min: 1
        },
    messages: {
       fieldname: {
           min: "Value must be greater than 0"
       }
    }
});
```