# Is minus zero a falsy value?

Tags: javascript, zero

I have not found yet any discussion or article about falsy values in Javascript where minus zero is mentioned while I see `!!-0` yielding `false`. Why is that?

Update:
I now think most authors summing up falsy values either do not know about `-0` being a value or mean by `0` both `+0` and `-0`.

Comment: @AnkitaKuchhadiya `-0` and `+0` are two distinct values in JS

Comment: `-0` is `false`. There's little to distinguish it from `+0` other than checking which `Infinity` results when using it as a denominator in division.

Comment: note that +0===-0

Comment: @Marco yeah `0` typically encompasses both `-0` and `+0` because the behaviour in almost all cases is the same. The negative zero value comes into play so rarely that specifically mentioning it in order to say "it works the same as positive zero" is a waste of everyone's time - the reader and the writer of something. Hence why `0` is an acceptable shortcut that means "either zero"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check the value given is a positive or negative integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037669/how-to-check-the-value-given-is-a-positive-or-negative-integer)

Comment: @DzmitryKrivolap but `Object.is(+0, -0)` returns false

Comment: It also may be interesting.
https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/why-does-javascript-have-0-9b6e1965a075

Comment: Kindly look : https://hackernoon.com/negative-zero-bbd5fd790af3

Comment: IIRC the spec actually mentions that (briefly) *if the value is +0 or -0, return false* in the abatract `ToBoolean` operation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply put, [the ECMAScript specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-toboolean) states that the boolean conversion of `-0` results in `false`. This is stated in the table of conversions for the abstract operation `ToBoolean`, section 7.1.2.

> If *argument* is **+0**, **-0**, or **NaN**, return **false**; otherwise return **true**.

Answer (score 0):

Here is why:
the -0 here is first calculated. It won't calculate just the negative sign itself, thus it includes the digit. It then outputs `0`
Then it is run through the `!` operator two times. The first `!` operator converts or parses `0` into a boolean, and then inverts or falsifies the boolean.
`!0` returns `true`
The second inverts it again, returning `false`

Comment: "*It then outputs `0`", incorrect: `-0` results in a *negative zero*, it'd [a different value than `0`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223359/are-0-and-0-the-same)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good question. Javascript does distinguish -0.0 from 0.0. (And IEEE754 does too.)
We can test this with:

```
var X = -0.0; X
-> "-0"
```

So it is a value distinct from 0.0.

```
`!-0.0` -> true
```

So you are right, lists of falsy values should explicitly list -0.0 too.

Probably they dont list it because:

```
0.0 === -0.0   -> true
```

However that is not a good reason if we consider that javascript is inconsistent in some relations (e.g. non-transitive).